# Debugging TypeScript AWS CDK application

Tags: typescript, debugging, aws-cdk

Is it possible to debug an AWS CDK TypeScript application? If need for example check which value are in particular variable?

For example in Java are breakpoints.
But how can i check that flow goes in the expected way, if have:
`if (someVariable) {...}` in TypeScript code? How can check that `if` condition is true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can debug AWS CDK applications by simply running it in the language that it is written in. This is easily doable in both Jetbrains IDE's or VSCode. Just execute the `index.ts` or `app.py` in debug mode.

The only problem is that context variables in AWS CDK are not available. I uncomment these manually while debugging.

For typescript, you execute the Javascript file and it should help you to debug to make the changes in Typescript

[image]

Comment: You can debug with context variables.   See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62292674/how-can-i-configure-jetbrains-products-to-debug-cdk-typescript-applications-that/69378838#69378838

Answer (score 3):

The guys from DevopsStart created exactly what you are looking for.

[CDK Debugging in VSCode](https://devopstar.com/2020/02/04/cdk-debugging-in-vscode).

Be aware that when debugging your code `CDK tokens` still will be represented as "tokens" and not as there actual values.

**From the docs:**

> Tokens represent values that can only be resolved at a later time in
>   the lifecycle of an app. For example, the name of
>   an Amazon S3 bucket that you define in your AWS CDK app is only
>   allocated by AWS CloudFormation when you deploy your app. If you print
>   the bucket.bucketName attribute, which is a string, you see it
>   contains something like the following :
>
> `${TOKEN[Bucket.Name.1234]}`

[More about CDK tokens](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/tokens.html).

Comment: Awesome. Is it possible to have same in Intellij idea?

Comment: I don't think so since this extension designed to VS Code.

Comment: Cloud debugging is available in AWS ToolKit extension, for IntelliJ IDEA. See https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/11/announcing-cloud-debugging-beta/

Answer (score 2):

To debug a typescript cdk app `bin/<app>.ts` in vscode with context variables `account`, `region`, add to `.vscode/launch.json`:

```
{
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "name": "deploy",
    "skipFiles": [
        "<node_internals>/**"
    ],
    "runtimeArgs": [
        "-r", "./node_modules/ts-node/register/transpile-only"
    ],
    "args": [
        "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/aws-cdk/bin/cdk.js",
        "deploy",
        "-c", "account=<id>",
        "-c", "region=<region>",
    ]
}
```

Let the following be the content of `bin/<app>.ts`. Verify that `region` holds the context value `<id>`.

```
import { App } from 'aws-cdk-lib';
const app: App = new App()
let region: string = app.node.tryGetContext('region')
```

Answer (score 0):

From the project top folder:

```
$ mkdir .vscode/
$ touch .vscode/launch.json
```

Then modify launch.json as:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [


        {
        "type": "pwa-node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Program",
        "skipFiles": [
            "<node_internals>/**"
        ],
        "runtimeArgs": [
            "-r", "./node_modules/ts-node/register/transpile-only"
        ],
        "args": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/bin/cdk.ts"
        ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Notes:

1. Make sure the ${workspaceFolder}/bin/cdk.ts matches the entry point for your application in the bin folder.
2. Previous versions of this used "type": "node". In my case, I found that it only worked with "pwa-node".
3. Put in your break points and debug as usual.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have tried and successfully debug the CDK. Hope that could help:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Debug CDK TypeScript",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**"
            ],
            "program": "/path/to/your/project/node_modules/aws-cdk/bin/cdk",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "args": [
                "list",
            ],
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "env": {
                "APP_CONFIG": "config/app-config-default.json"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

My case is using a custom templated of CDK, the command that I run is `APP_CONFIG=config/app-config-default.json cdk list`.

You may need to change this line `"program": "/path/to/your/project/node_modules/aws-cdk/bin/cdk"` to fit current machine cdk's command path (try `which cdk` to know the path)