# How can I configure JetBrains products to debug CDK TypeScript applications that require a context value to be set?

Tags: typescript, debugging, webstorm, jetbrains-ide, aws-cdk

I have a CDK application where I am getting context values, like:

```
const stage: StageType = app.node.tryGetContext('stage');
```

I followed the JetBrains documentation for setting a run configuration using ts-node, however context is created by the CDK CLI. My code fails to run with the necessary context values.

Is there a way to debug, using using the CDK CLI to start the application?

Comment: the only thing i could imagine is to pass those context params as normal parameters to the debug configuration and on existence, transform them to context values. IMO its not possible to debug by calling the CDK command.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've had the same issue recently and just discovered a way to debug the CDK command via WebStorm.

Rather than debugging via `node` debug via `npm`. In my `package.json` I have a script of `cdk` that simply runs `cdk` (I think this is standard with the CDK?).

Then for the WebStorm configuration, use the `run` command, and the `cdk` script. In arguments you can now pass `synth -- -c stage='myStageContext'`

[image]

Comment: It worked initially, but now I keep getting the error `wrong line 35. Available lines 35`. Any ideas?